# Properly loading and editing an Excel Pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have an excel file where I am trying to edit some data on a pivot table from Excel. All I wish to do is subtract the "Bicycles on Road" volume from the "Total" for all timestamps before reaching the "Grand Total" row at the bottom (I have no need for the Crosswalk Volumes table afterwards). I was advised I can accomplish this using pandas dataframe. However, when trying to read and load the data, using the following code:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import pandas as pd

# Specify input directory
input_directory = "./"

# Create an empty list to store completed files
completed_files = []

# Loop through Excel files in the specified directory
for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
    # Construct full path to the Excel file
    file_path = os.path.join(input_directory, filename)

    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        df_tmv = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='TMV Table', skiprows=10, engine='openpyxl')
    elif filename.endswith(".xls"):
        df_tmv = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='TMV Table', skiprows=10)
    else:
        # Handle other cases or raise an error for unsupported file types
        print(f"Unsupported file type: {file_extension}")
        continue  # Skip unsupported files

    # Get the row index of the "Grand Total" cell
    grand_total_row = df_tmv[df_tmv.iloc[:, 1] == 'Grand Total'].index[0]

    # Use the location of "Grand Total" cell to determine the extent of the data
    totals_start_row = 11  # Assuming it starts from row 11
    totals_start_col = 3  # Assuming it starts from column C
    totals_end_row = grand_total_row - 1  # Exclude the "Grand Total" row
    totals_end_col = totals_start_col + df_tmv.shape[1] - 3

    # Create a copy of the original DataFrame for subtraction
    df_tmv_without_bikes = df_tmv.copy()

    # Iterate through rows with a step of 8 (every 8th row)
    for row in range(totals_start_row, totals_start_row + totals_end_row, 8):
        # Subtract "Bicycles on Road" row from the total traffic volume row
        df_tmv_without_bikes.iloc[row:row + 8, totals_start_col:] = df_tmv.iloc[row:row + 8, totals_start_col:].astype(float) - df_tmv.iloc[row + 7, totals_start_col:].astype(float)

    # Write modified DataFrame to a new sheet
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book = load_workbook(file_path)
        df_tmv_without_bikes.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TMV Table without Bikes', index=False)
        writer.save()

    completed_files.append(filename)

print("The following files have been modified:")
for file in completed_files:
    print(file)
```

the output shows

```
     Unnamed: 0         Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2
0           NaN                NaN         NaN
1           NaN                NaN         NaN
2           NaN                NaN         NaN
3           NaN                NaN         NaN
4           NaN                NaN         NaN
..          ...                ...         ...
254         NaN                NaN         NaN
255         NaN                NaN         NaN
256         NaN                NaN         NaN
257         NaN                NaN         NaN
258         NaN  Crosswalk Volumes         NaN

[259 rows x 3 columns]
```

So clearly the dataframe is either not loading or reading properly (also the size of the dataframe is wrong) -- which left me quite stumped because I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgo7j.png) of my excel file if the data is unique in some way that is causing this. Any help or feedback that can point me in the right direction is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please share relevant code, specifically how you call `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: load the excel with pandas and transpose the object with pandas_object.T

Comment: pandas_object.T still returns Unnamed elements and NaN values

Comment: Please try to provide a MRE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can provide the rest of the code, however, the main issue right now is properly reading and loading the pivot table into my dataframe.